# android app error... java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity

Tags: android, build

First, thank you for your interest on my problem..!

My error occurs during implementing the builded app on my smartphone.

After the specific activity, the app stops with "My application keeps stopping" message.

The error code on logcat is below..

```
2021-06-30 07:52:49.525 29940-29940/com.taehoon.milapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.taehoon.milapp, PID: 29940
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.taehoon.milapp/com.taehoon.milapp.sittaba2}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:5212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:5163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:5114)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:46)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1637)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchPause(FragmentManager.java:3090)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchPause(FragmentController.java:284)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPause(FragmentActivity.java:390)
    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:8383)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1510)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:5202)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:5163) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:5114) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:46) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

and the located codes(sittaba2) is below.

```
package com.taehoon.milapp
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_sittaba2.*

class sittaba2 : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    onDestroy()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sittaba2)

    Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.bridge).override(200, 200).into(imageView131)

    val intent = Intent(this, sittaba3::class.java)

    val value = object : CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            mTextField27.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            //mTextField3.setText("끝")
            startActivity(intent)
            onDestroy()
        }

    }.start()

    imageButton63.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(intent)
        onDestroy()
    }
}
```

}

In my humble opinion.. the "Destroy" has some problems... what can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't call onDestroy, it is called by system and you can only override it.

To finish your current Activity, call this:

```
finish()
```